# Metapost: how to build a cycle path for the picture to hatchfill?

Tags: metapost, paths, cross-hatching

Followed is a minimum example to show my problem. I want to `hatchfill` the Cee section. I don't know how to build the `cycle path` for the hatch. I have tried `buildcycle` but failed. How can I add the `corner radius` to the cycle path?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{luamplib}

\begin{mplibcode}
  warningcheck := 0;
  input hatching
  
  beginfig(1)
    pair p[];
    picture Cee;
    numeric i;
    
    u = 1 / 2 * 1mm;

    D := 300 * u;
    B := 150 * u;
    t := 5 * u;
    L := 55 * u;
    r := 13 * u;
    
    p0 = (B/2 - r - t, D/2);
    p1 = (-(B/2 - r - t), D/2);
    p2 = (-B/2, D/2 - t - r);
    p3 = (-B/2, -(D/2 - 2 * t - r));
    p4 = (-(B/2 - r - t), -(D/2 - t));
    p5 = (B/2 - r - 2 * t, -(D/2 - t));
    p6 = (B/2 - t, -(D/2 - 2 * t - r));
    p7 = (B/2 - t, -(D/2 - t - L));
    p8 = (B/2 - 2 * t, -(D/2 - t - L));
    p9 = (B/2 - 2 * t, -(D/2 - 2 * t - r));
    p10 = (B/2 - 2 * t - r, -(D/2 - 2 * t));
    p11 = (-(B/2 - r - t), -(D/2 - 2 * t));
    p12 = (-(B/2 - t), -(D/2 - 2 * t - r));
    p13 = (-(B/2 - t), D/2 - t - r);
    p14 = (-(B/2 - t - r), D/2 - t);
    p15 = (B/2 - r - t, D/2 - t);
  
    Cee = image(
      draw p0 -- p1;
      draw quartercircle scaled 2(r+t) rotated (90) shifted (p1 - (0, r+t));
      draw p2 -- p3;
      draw quartercircle scaled 2(r+t) rotated (180) shifted (p3 + (r+t, 0));
      draw p4 -- p5;
      draw quartercircle scaled 2(r+t) rotated (270) shifted (p6 - (r+t, 0));
      draw p6 -- p7 -- p8 -- p9;
      draw quartercircle scaled 2r rotated (270) shifted (p10 + (0,r));
      draw p10 -- p11;
      draw quartercircle scaled 2r rotated (180) shifted (p11 + (0, r));
      draw p12 -- p13;
      draw quartercircle scaled 2r rotated (90) shifted (p13 + (r, 0));
      draw p14 -- p15 -- p0;
    );

    draw Cee;
    % hatchfill Cee withcolor (45, 2mm, -.5bp); % how can I build a cycle path for the picture??

    for i = 0 upto 15:
      label(decimal(i), p[i]);
    endfor;
  endfig;
\end{mplibcode}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect `path` variables as well as `pair` variables in a `path`.  So (with some simplification) try this:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
  input hatching
  
    pair p[];
    path Cee;
    numeric B, D, L, t, r, u;
    u = 1/2 mm;
    D = 300 u;
    B = 150 u;
    t = 5 u;
    L = 55 u;
    r = 13 u;
    
    p0 = (B/2 - r - t, D/2);
    p1 = (-(B/2 - r - t), D/2);
    p3 = (-B/2, -(D/2 - 2 * t - r));
    p6 = (B/2 - t, -(D/2 - 2 * t - r));
    p7 = (B/2 - t, -(D/2 - t - L));
    p8 = (B/2 - 2 * t, -(D/2 - t - L));
    p10 = (B/2 - 2 * t - r, -(D/2 - 2 * t));
    p11 = (-(B/2 - r - t), -(D/2 - 2 * t));
    p13 = (-(B/2 - t), D/2 - t - r);
    p15 = (B/2 - r - t, D/2 - t);
 
    Cee = 
      p0 -- 
      quartercircle scaled 2(r+t) rotated  90 shifted (p1 - (0, r+t)) -- 
      quartercircle scaled 2(r+t) rotated 180 shifted (p3 + (r+t, 0)) --
      quartercircle scaled 2(r+t) rotated 270 shifted (p6 - (r+t, 0)) -- 
      p7 -- p8 -- 
      reverse quartercircle scaled 2r rotated 270 shifted (p10 + (0,r)) --
      reverse quartercircle scaled 2r rotated 180 shifted (p11 + (0, r)) --
      reverse quartercircle scaled 2r rotated 90 shifted (p13 + (r, 0)) -- 
      p15 -- cycle;

    draw Cee;
    hatchfill Cee withcolor (45, 2mm, -.5bp); 

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

compile this with `lualatex` to get a PDF showing this:

[image]

Comment: Connecting `path` (corner radius) with `pair` (point) is amazing and more simple. Glad to know it. Thanks.